# posting on facebook wall at a scheduled time by the user

Tags: c#, facebook

hi i have developed an application where end user can post something to his wall using access_token. But the problem is the end user want to schedule a time and he wanted to post at that scheduled time. how should i achieve this in c#. waiting for reply urgently.

Comment: _You want a coffee or a cold beverage while you’re waiting …?_

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer, and check the dateTime when the person wants to post, and simply post the message

Comment: Correct, but I think the OP was hoping you'd write his app for him